# Seleniumで複数階になっているドロップダウンメニューの選択の仕方を知りたい

Tags: python, selenium

単層での選択は可能なのですが、複数層になるとエラーが起きてしまいます。

できればnameやIDなど、日本語で表示されているものを入力して選択したいです。

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text(u"1段階目サンプル").click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text(u"2段階目サンプル").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("3段階目サンプル").click()
```

ご教授いただけば幸いです、よろしくお願いいたします。